# How to remove all junk emails from the junk email folder?

Tags: ipad

I have many emails in the junk folder in my yahoo email. How do I delete them all at one time using my iPad.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the junk folder-> select 'Edit' in the right corner-> then select 'Delete All'.
Good luck.